# Best way to call multiple of methods in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am searching for a solution where I can add multiple method calls to an thread.
A normal Thread call only be started with one method call, i would like to add multiple independent methods calls. It could be thousands of methods to be called from a thread so a thread for every method call is not possible. I thought of for example 10 threads which are getting methods to call. Or is a threadpool the better approach?

Something like this would be nice:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();
t1.Add(DoWork(1));
t1.Add(DoWork(2));
t2.Add(DoWork(3));
t2.Add(DoWork(4));
t1.Start(); t2.Start();
```

Comment: Maybe, a new thread that calls multiple methods.

Comment: If the method calls are "independent," why do they need to be performed by the same thread? If you're just trying to reduce the number of threads your application uses, consider using a thread pool instead, and let the method calls be distributed across it.

Comment: My usual advice is to stay away from low level classes like Thread and Threadpool unless you have a serious reason. You should have a look at the higher level classes like Task, Parallel, PLINQ or BackgroundWorker instead.

Answer (score 3):

Start the thread with one method that calls all the other methods. This can be simplified by using an [anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions):

```cs
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => {
    DoWork(1);
    DoWork(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function which calls all those methods, and then pass that to the thread. But you should really avoid using raw threads if you can. If all these are just independent operations which need to be performed, why not just run them as `Task`s?